# Linebreaks are ignored in Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html, line-breaks

I receive a text with linebreaks from an API but I can't get the linebreaks to work.

This is a part of the text I want to shown. http://pastebin.com/CLnq16mP (pasted it there because the formatting on stackoverflow wasnt correct.)

I tried this:

```
termsAndConditionsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html><body>" + textResponse.getText() + "</body></html>"));
```

and this:

```
termsAndConditionsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textResponse.getText()));
```

but the linebreaks (\r\n) and spaces are always ignored.

How can I fix this?

Comment: should replace the \r\n with <br> tag and replace the spaces you want to keep with &nbsp; before parsing the HTML

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since its html try using

```
</br>
```

You can replace all \r\n and spaces in your text by doing something like this:

```
    //message is your string.

    message = message.replace("\r\n","<br />");
    message = message.replace(" ","&nbsp;");
    termsAndConditionsTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message));
```

Good Luck!

Comment: what about the \r char and the "ignored" spaces ? also </br> is not valid.

Comment: You can replace \r\n with <br /> the same way instead of just \n. html does not recognize \n or \r it does know <br /> though. and space can be replaced with &nbsp

Comment: So the \r will remain at the end of all the lines ?

Comment: so \r\n is the same as <br />. They both signify a line break. Its just that that in some systems (windows) they use \r\n, in others they use just \n. So you should be fine with just replacing all \r\n with <br />. Then replacing all spaces with &nbsp; Ill update answer a bit, try it and see what it looks like.

Comment: The pasted text contains those \r\n, that's why I asked this. Replacing only the \n in this case will keep the \r at the end of all the lines

Answer (score 4):

As the text is pre-formatted, even with indentation, you could use the `<pre>` tag.

```
<pre>
   your text.
</pre>
```

But the newlines evidently where escaped: `\r\n` so you still have to convert:

```
message = message.replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

The same holds for `\/`.

If you want to introduce bold, hyperlinks and such, then the `<pre>` tag fails, as it can only contain preformatted as-is text,